# string hints in different languages

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unity3d.

Somewhere I have hints appearing in the bottom of the HUD (Something like "press A for Action"). I want my game to support more languages and I don't want these hints to be hard-coded in the script.

What is the most elegant way to solve this task? I am thinking about txt file, where I will have all my hints in all languages. But I am not sure, if it is a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio, and do your C# coding in there, you should be able to make use of the Resources files. That's the way those programs use Localization. There's a file for each language, and a key for the phrase. Depending on the set language, it will choose the correct Resources file, if it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcoding is not that bad if you do it correctly.

For example create an abstract class with all the messages that you want to have and language autodetection:

```
public abstract class Lang {

  static Lang currentLang;

  public static Lang Get {
    get {
      if(currentLang == null)
        switch(Application.systemLanguage) {
        case SystemLanguage.Polish:
          currentLang=new LangPL();
          break;
        default:
        case SystemLanguage.English:
          currentLang=new LangEN();
          break;
        }

      return currentLang;
    }
  }

  public abstract string MenuTime {get;}
  public abstract string MenuPoints {get;}
  public abstract string YouWon {get;}
  public abstract string YouLost {get;}
  public abstract string Point(int p);

}
```

And then implement each language as a separate class:

```
public class LangPL:Lang {
  public override string MenuTime {get {return "CZAS";}}
  public override string MenuPoints {get {return "WYNIK";}}
  public override string YouWon {get {return "Gratuluję, wygrałeś!";}}
  public override string YouLost{get {return "Może następnym razem...";}}
  public override string Point(int p) {
    if(p == 1)
      return "1 punkt";
    return p+" punktów";
  }
}


public class LangEN:Lang {
  public override string MenuTime {get {return "TIME";}}
  public override string MenuPoints {get {return "SCORE";}}
  public override string YouWon {get {return "You won!";}}
  public override string YouLost{get {return "Maybe next time...";}}
  public override string Point(int p) {
    if(p == 1)
      return "1 point";
    return p+" points";
  }
}
```

Usage is a simple:

```
GUILayout.Label(Lang.Get.YouWon);
GUILayout.Label(Lang.Get.Point(5));
```

This way you have most control, and can easily support complex translations. Also this approach helps to trim down on errors - if you forget or misstype a text anywhere it throws a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think, I will implement it exactly like that!

Answer (score 3):

A common way that is used is to have an XML-file for each language. The XML-file should contain every phrase you use in your game with a unique ID.

In your code, you can then get the correct phrase out of the current language's XML, using the correct ID.

If you don't know about XML files, read this tutorial about using XML files in Unity: http://xeophin.net/en/blog/2010/05/13/reading-strings-out-xml-file-using-c-unity-3d

However if you are willing to spend some money on your game, you should check this out: http://u3d.as/content/rodrigo-barros/my-menu/32E

I haven't tried that yet but it seems good.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a Javascript script or a C# script for each language and then depending of the language choosen, you call the specific script.

e.g

```
public class English : MonoBehaviour{
  public string jump = "Press 'space' to jump";
  //etc
}

public class French : MonoBehaviour{
  public string jump = "Appuyer sur 'espace' pour sauter";
  //etc
}
```

In your function for GUIText

```
public GameController gameController;
public GUIText text;

private string languageSelected;// obtain from the user input on language selection (better if registered in the gameController)

void Awake(){
  languageSelected = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(gameController.languageSelected));
  // where languageSelected will be e.g English
  text.text = languageSelected.jump;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting option

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against embedding text into your code. It will slow down the localization process (having to look through code to find text is not the quickest and best way to approach localization).

Go with separate files. It's easier to maintain and translators don't have to access the code.

Have a look at l2 localization. It's a pretty handy Unity plugin that allows you to manage translations of your game.

All your localized strings in a single Google Spreadsheet. Once set up, all you need to do is fill it out to see the results in the game.

I am a game translator myself and happen to be managing a small team of game translators called Level Up Translation. We posted a beginner's guide for [localization in Unity](http://www.leveluptranslation.com/single-post/7-tips-for-localizing-your-indie-game-in-unity) in our blog a couple of months ago. Feel free to check it out!

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can save language file for ***france.txt***  in format:

```
hello=Bonjour
goodbye=Au Revoir
```

And than, read file and convert it to dictionary:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("france.txt");
var dict = lines.Select(l => l.Split('=')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

Now you can read from dictionary by key:

```
string hello = dict["hello"];
```